# How can I store music on an android phone without allowing the user to be able to download it and use it?

Tags: android, encryption, copy-protection

I am working on an app that connects to a media providing site and downloads mp3 files to the user phone. I would like for the user to be unable to copy these files off the phone but only listen to them through my app.

I am currently trying to encrypt the files using DES and encryption and decrypt and play the file in bits in the app. This is however not working. Is there a better way of achieving my end goal or has anyone else implemented a similar solution?

Thanks

P

Answer (score 0):

If you use DES (a private key or symmetric-key algorithm) you need to store you the decryption key in your app. Remember this is Android's byte code, much easier to disassemble to retrieve key.

Think of other [DRM alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management#Table_of_DRM_technologies_and_associated_devices).

Comment: do you know of any specific ones. im having tough time nailing one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android's internal storage, the file system you create can only be accessed by your app.  However, due to the open nature of Android there are many "Rooted" android ROMs available that allow public access to these files.