# Protecting Music files - filesystem

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am needing to build an Android application that has music/audio files downloaded from a webservice and ultimately stored on the filesystem for playing within the app, but I need to prevent the user from being able to access and play the files, rooted or not.

My first instinct is to encrypt them before storing to the filesystem, but I'm not sure which encryption algorithms I should be focused on, as well as whether it makes a difference that these are binary files being encrypted vs. plain text files (I'm reading posts about encryption not working correctly for audio files).

Is there a better way to approach this kind of thing?  I see a similar question to this has been asked, but it unfortunately has no solid answers:

[How can I store music on an android phone without allowing the user to be able to download it and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355219/how-can-i-store-music-on-an-android-phone-without-allowing-the-user-to-be-able-t)

My apologies if I have overlooked how this can be accomplished.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just curious, what music is going to be available in the system that won't be available on the internet already?

Comment: I can't think of any past DRM scheme that hasn't been defeated in some way. Go for it if you want, but all the lockdown in the world won't stop people if they want it. Ask Disney, Sony, EA, Amazon, etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking how to create a [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) system.  It is a controversial topic, and there is no direct answer.  The site [Defective by Design](http://www.defectivebydesign.org/what_is_drm_digital_restrictions_management) discusses the negative aspects to DRM systems from the perspective of the user.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response and links.  This is information we can take back to the potential client, and it's good to know that this is probably our only route to take for getting anything in place for this kind of thing.  I fully understand there is no possible way to 'fully' protect against it, of course.  I'm thinking the client just wants to be able to add some level of protection against people being freely able to snag the music off the device and load onto their computers/mp3 players.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question really depends on how you define "the user".  If you mean the average, ordinary user, you could really encrypt the file any way you like.  Even something as trivial as XORing the file would work.

However, if the "user" you are talking about is a determined individual with a decent amount of knowledge and technical aptitude, the simple answer is that you can't.  It is trivially easy to get the java source out of a .class file so anyone who really wants to get at those files can look at your code to find out how you encrypted it and then reverse engineer it.

Simply put, if your client can read the file, any user who has the client can read the file (with or without using your client).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should have clarified in my post, but this is a client request and not something I personally want to accomplish.  I just was not sure if there was a simple or standard approach to it.  I definitely understand that there is no 'fullproof' way against this; I'm sure the client just wants some level of protection.  Regardless, this type of information is something we can take back to the client, along with dsh's answer regarding the DRM system.  Thanks for the response